# How can i make LocalTime instance variable accept json data based on my specific format?

Tags: java, json, firebase-realtime-database

im having a problem, im basically getting data as Json objects from an API,
the field `time` in the Json object is set to a format like this: `HH:mm`

I am having a problem filling in LocalTime object since its defualt format looks like this `23:37:48.120473200` (LocalTime is an instance variable in my `Message` class)

how can i solve this?

Message class

```
public class Message {
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime time;
    private String message;
    private String messageId;


    public Message(LocalDate date, LocalTime time, String message, String messageId) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.message = message;
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" +
                "date='" + date + '\'' +
                ", time='" + time + '\'' +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", messageId='" + messageId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the format of the data you receive is `hh:mm`? That is an incomplete pattern because `hh` is hours of day in 12h format, but without an *AM/PM* you won't be able to tell the correct time. However, you can parse a `String` formatted as `HH:mm` (`HH`: hour of day in 24h format) like `LocalTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")`.

Comment: @deHaar Sorry my bad, its in HH:mm, the format of the data i recieve is hh:mm, im 100% sure. When i use postman, i see something like this `"time":"03:23"`, but the time is of string ofcourse so idk.

Comment: You have to specify the input format with a `DateTimeFormatter`, that's it. The method `LocalTime.parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)` will fill up the remaining units with 0.

Comment: but where should i add it? im getting data from firebase api realtime database, i cant fill it in because the moment i try to it gives me an error saying the list is empty, which means there was an error filling up the Message objects (probablt caused by incorrect format). Where should i add this `LocalTime.parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse( "03:23" )
```

## Details

Text in format of hour in 24-hour clock with padding zero, followed by a COLON and minute with padding zero, complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for textual date-time formats.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing such text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "03:23" ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input ) ;
```

If you use a framework for parsing your JSON, you should be able to ask the framework to do this parsing for you. The major JSON frameworks have been updated to leverage the *java.time* classes.